# App crashes when I click on side bar menu

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, swift4.2, side-menu

Before it worked, when I made the update iOS 13 and updated xCode to 11, I am not able to use the side bar. The application is using the pod SideMenuController and when I click on the icon of side menu to show it, it crashes and shows me this message:

---

```
Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3899.22.15/UIApplication.m:5311

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'
```

Comment: could you please paste your code before we answer you

Answer (score 0):

I will answer why didn't I show the code, because I didn't made it, the engineer that was before me made it with a pod named SideMenuController. So I'm not familiar with the project or the code inside. I did a lot of research and I fixed it and I wanted to share the solution with you. ( PS: I don't know how it worked ) in the description of the pod, I needed to comment this line:

```
 SideMenuController.preferences.animating.transitionAnimator = FadeAnimator.self
```

and another line to change from :

```
SideMenuController.preferences.animating.statusBarBehaviour = .horizontalPan
```

To this line :

```
  SideMenuController.preferences.animating.statusBarBehaviour = .showUnderlay
```

And it worked like magic, Thank you guys